# Localhost refused to connect in a working server with LAMP and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am getting the error 'refused to connect' on my localhost in a specific project, but the server is perfectly working for all other projects. I'm on a Linux Mint 20 with LAMP (Apache, MySQL, PHP) and Wordpress.

The project is a wordpress site which I moved (exported) from my remote server using Duplicator plugin and imported it on the localhost, everything was correctly installed. I have done this process several times on the remote server with no issues. When I tried now to install in a localserver, I got that error.

I guess there is no relation with Apache configuration, because If I delete Wordpress I can see a index.php working again (Hello World just for testing purpose).

Does anybody know what could be the possible reason of this connection refused? Any special configuration on Wordpress maybe?

[image]

**/var/log/apache2/error.log**

```
[Sun Mar 06 15:57:12.269041 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 49648] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Mar 06 15:57:12.383850 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 77793] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 06 15:57:12.383885 2022] [core:notice] [pid 77793] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Mar 06 15:57:44.517430 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 77793] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Mar 06 15:57:44.605141 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 77990] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 06 15:57:44.605185 2022] [core:notice] [pid 77990] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Mar 06 15:58:41.869026 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 77990] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Mar 06 15:58:41.944690 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 78194] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 06 15:58:41.944739 2022] [core:notice] [pid 78194] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Mar 06 16:00:12.008975 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 78197] [client 127.0.0.1:53488] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/br/wp-cont>
[Sun Mar 06 16:00:12.511655 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 78197] [client 127.0.0.1:53488] add_to_cart_fragments is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use woocommerce_add_to_car>
[Sun Mar 06 16:02:08.406739 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 78194] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Mar 06 16:02:08.520739 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 78743] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 06 16:02:08.520792 2022] [core:notice] [pid 78743] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Mar 06 16:13:15.711811 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 79048] [client 127.0.0.1:53896] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/br/wp-cont>
[Sun Mar 06 16:13:16.205011 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 79048] [client 127.0.0.1:53896] add_to_cart_fragments is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use woocommerce_add_to_car>
[Sun Mar 06 16:23:48.307054 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 82580] [client 127.0.0.1:54046] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/br/wp-cont>
[Sun Mar 06 16:23:50.125437 2022] [php7:notice] [pid 82580] [client 127.0.0.1:54046] add_to_cart_fragments is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use woocommerce_add_to_car>
```

**/var/log/apache2/access.log**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2022:18:10:56 -0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:11:38 -0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=cashcowrepublic HTTP/1.1" 200 54623 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) App>
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:11:39 -0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/messages.php?l=en&v=4.9.5deb2 HTTP/1.1" 200 9390 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.>
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:11:39 -0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6401807181ltr&server=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 21500 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64>
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:11:39 -0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/whitelist.php?v=4.9.5deb2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1158 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (>
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:11:39 -0300] "POST /phpmyadmin/ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2733 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) >
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:11:39 -0300] "POST /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?ajax_request=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 6330 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36>
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:11:39 -0300] "POST /phpmyadmin/ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2854 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) >
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:11:39 -0300] "POST /phpmyadmin/ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2742 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) >
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2022:18:12:37 -0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2022:18:30:51 -0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2022:18:31:51 -0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:35:34 -0300] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2831 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)>
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:18:48:43 -0300] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2829 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)>
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2022:18:54:00 -0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2022:18:55:44 -0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - root [06/Mar/2022:19:00:39 -0300] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2845 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)>
```

Comment: have you checked error logs?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone no I haven't. Which file should I check?

Comment: the ones in `/var/log/apache2` folder

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I posted the lasts log info but there is no relation with "connection refused", please check.

Comment: `refused to connect` does not sound like a standard error - is that really *exactly* what you see?  Does the msg indicate if it is related to Apache or MySQL?  "*If I delete Wordpress I can see the index.php working again*" - what `index.php` do you mean?  You would normally copy WP files into an empty directory, so there would be nothing left if you remove WP.  Even if you copy WP into a dir with files (you should not), it has its own `index.php` so would overwrite one of your own.  "*everything was correctly installed*" - can you describe what you did?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I got the message ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, I put the image on description, I think it is related to Apache, please check. The index is just a Hello World for testing purpose, don't worry about this point, I have done the same installation on remote server and was ok, the problem is on localhost.

Comment: I don't think swapping one index.php for another would cause the site to go from working to becoming unreachable like that ... Are you changing the URL you're visiting also?

Comment: @Don'tPanic no, i'm on the same URL. Is not about swapping. When I DELETE wordpress files, the connection is back to normal. That mean is something related to Wordpress.

Comment: According to your description, you are removing WP files, and adding your own.  As I said, if everything else remains the same (Apache config, same vhost, same domain name, files in same dir on filesystem ...), I don't think swapping files like that would cause the site to become unreachable.  The error you show seems to indicate a bigger issue, like Apache down, or not configured to respond to this host, or network down, etc.  Or maybe file permissions, are the WP files readable by Apache?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've got 3 other projects (not WP) on the same localhost which is working perfectly, so I think cannot be Apache, network nor permission from this part (set all to 777). I've checked anyway. Only on the WP I got the error on localhost, not readable till now. This same WP, when installed on a shared remote server, it works.

Comment: "*...3 other projects ... on the same localhost which is working perfectly, so I think cannot be Apache, network nor permission*" - that logic does not follow.  Do you have 3 separate vhosts configured? Surely you are not deleting files and swapping in new ones to switch between projects - so you probably have multiple vhost configs, and maybe a new one for the new WP project.  Just bcs one vhost config works does not mean the new WP one is.  As a random eg (not saying you have this problem, just an eg) if the new vhost has the wrong `DocumentRoot` it won't work while your others do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242663/discussion-between-kelson-batista-and-dont-panic).